# INvalid argument foreach laravel when isnsert multiple rows

Tags: laravel

i want to update status receive to yes after that data also insert to other table multiple rows, i using ajax

this is my controller

```
  public function bulkupdate(Request $request, ItemPR $item_code)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
    $item_code = $request->item_code;
    $item = ItemPR::whereIn('item_code', explode(",", $item_code))->update(['received'=> 'yes']);
    $data = [];
    foreach($item as $value){
        $data[] = [
            'item_code' => $value->item_code,
        ];
    }}
    WarehouseInventory::insert($data);
    return response()->json(['success'=>"Products Updated successfully."]);
}
```

but i getting error like this

```
invalid argument for suplied foreach
```

how to fix that ?
plis help
thanks

Comment: What is `$pr_items`? I would wager it's not an iterable item, like an `array`. If you're sending this from a form, is the input's name `item_code` or `item_code[]`?

Comment: how fix that, i newbie

Comment: You’re iterating through $pr_items, but the way it’s named suggests that it is just one item code.

Comment: i have been edited my questions,, plis check this,,,but same the error

Comment: You need to add `->get()` to the end of your query, otherwise isn't not usable in a `foreach`... You also need to read up on the fundamentals of PHP and Laravel; these are common issues that can be avoided by knowing what a variable is, how it can be used, or how to refactor so you can use it as required.